# .preventDefault() only working on first click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an image gallery where the image and the previous/next links under the image are repopulated using AJAX. I want to prevent the links for working here when the user has JS (so that the AJAX method is used), but only when the page is loaded the first time is this working.

This is the code that I have on the page to stop the links working -

```
/** Prevent the default links from working when clicking on an ajax link */
$('#attachment-body a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And here is an example of one of the links -

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($attachment->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $attachment->post_name; ?>" rel="attachment" onclick="set_centre_image(<?php echo $attachment->ID; ?>, <?php echo $value_for_writing; ?>)">
    <img src="<?php echo $img_src[0]; ?>" />
</a>
```

I'm guessing that this has something to do with the elements that should have their defaults disabled being reloaded with AJAX, but if that is the case, is there a way around it. And if it is not the case, does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your elements get replaced, your click handlers get trashed. You can overcome this problem by making use of event delegation. I suggest the use of [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#attachment-body').delegate("a", "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thanks Karim, that seems to mostly work, but in IE only the first link within `#attachment-body` is not reloading the whole page. The other links are evern ignoring the `prevenDefault()` command before the content has been refreshed with AJAX. Every other browser is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do the ajax requests add new DOM elements? If so you can try this:

```
$('#attachment-body a').live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `attachment-body` is already on the page. It first has it's content emptied and then is repopulated with the AJAX content. However, taking your example and repeating it for every element that I wish to stop loading on seems to have work in all browsers, with the exception of one small error in IE that I am trying to fix. Thanks.